# conditional slicing of scipy sparse matrix

Tags: scipy, sparse-matrix

Apologies if this is a duplicate.

I have got a large `coo_matrix` (say `x`) returned by another function, which I need to slice on rows matching conditions in a numpy array `a` with same number of rows and a single column (with binary values).

I am using scipy.sparse.hstack([x,a]) to concatenate the two, in order to do something like this

```
x1 = x[x[:,-1] == 0]
x2 = x[x[:,-1] == 1]
```

but that fails with the following error.

```
TypeError: 'coo_matrix' object is not subscriptable
```

`x.toarray()` solution doesn't work due to `MemoryError`.

Is there a way to do the above? I need the sliced matrices as `coo_matrix` in the end.

Comment: You should be more explicit about that obvious failure.  However I can guess that you are being told that `coo` doesn't support indexing.  Other formats like `csr` and `lil` do support indexing.  That said, `x[..]==0` is going to be a problem, since in a sparse matrix most elements will be 0. But you might make a mask with `x1=x[:,-1].toarray()`, the dense last column.

Comment: Thanks paul, I have updated the question with the specific error.

Comment: As I suspected, indexing has not been implemented for `coo` format matrices.  It's just too slow and awkward for that representation.  I added a note to my answer about using array `a`, without the `hstack`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a random `csr` format matrix:

```
In [795]: M = sparse.random(20,10,.2,'csr')
```

Get a dense 1d array of the last column.  (I don't want a matrix or 2d array from the matrix):

```
In [805]: M1 = M[:,-1].A.ravel()
```

Now I can use that as a row mask:

```
In [808]: M[M1==0,:]
Out[808]: 
<16x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 30 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [809]: M[M1>0,:]
Out[809]: 
<4x10 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Trying to mask with the sparse column does not work:

```
M[M[:,-1]>0,:]
IndexError: Indexing with sparse matrices is not supported except boolean indexing where matrix and index are equal shapes.
```

---

Indexing of `csr` matrices is done with matrix multiplication.  The indices are turned into a sparse matrix of 1 and 0, which with multiplication ends up selecting the desired rows.  Sparse summation is also done with multiplication.

Row indexing from `lil` format is also easy.

[How to get views on sparse matrices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022362/how-to-get-views-on-sparse-matrices/52022423#52022423)

---

Rereading your question, I'd suggest keeping `x` and `a` separate.  Since `a` is already dense, just use

```
M1 = a.ravel()    # if a is (n,1) array
M1 = a.A1         # if a is (n,1) np.matrix
```

to make a 1d `ndarray`, as in [805] above.  And since it has binary values, and you are just interested in the 0 vs 1

```
M1 = M1.astype(bool)
```

and

```
M[~M1,:]
M[M1,:]
```

for the two subsets.

Again, if it wasn't clear, we can't index the `coo` format matrix.  It has to be `csr` or `lil` format.

Comment: Thanks Paul and sorry for my patchy response. This works for me. Since my original sparse matrix is in `coo` format, I used `x.tocsr()` to convert the original matrix to `csr` format. I am assuming that this format would work fine when I reuse the matrix later in the code. If not I will probably simply recast it to `coo`. Finally, is there any preferred method between `csr` and `lil`? Thanks again, I will let you do any further edits in response to this comment and will mark it correct.